# How to set the datasource to a gridview in a Mono Android application?

Tags: c#, android, .net, gridview, mono

How do I set a datasource to an Android application?

Like in .NET, we do `gridview.datasource = datatable;` My service returns a datatable which has the records from my database. Now I need to set the gridview's datasource as the datatable returned from my service. I would like to do the same in Android Mono.

(I am new to Android development.)

Comment: go [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) and take the best subclass that fits your needs

Answer (score 0):

Use [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) to achieve that. Create your adapter and call `gridView.setAdapter()`. There is a guide in *[Grid View](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)*.

Comment: I want to just display datas from my database... SO i would not need to add any events to click.. and can i get a more relevant example than the Image Adapter. Thanks for the effort